# How to use AppCenter Analytics on .net Core WebApi backend?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-app-center

I'm able to send events to appcenter.ms from my XamarinForms App . However, sending the events requires the app secret key to be added to the android/ios app itself. This key can be easily extracted using a decompiler.

On my webapi backend, like the Xamarin app, I tried adding the nuget package and then in Startup.cs

```
  AppCenter.Start("SECTETKEYHERE", typeof(Analytics));
```

And then tracking the event this way

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("MyTestEvent",new Dictionary<string, string>{{"EventNameHere","EventValueHere"}});
```

However, no event data ever arrives in the appcenter dashboard.

So my question is , how do I use the trackevent functionality on the serverside, or , at the very least, store the key on the app side securely(I'd really rather not do this).

My fallback plan is to use google analytics as it works fine .

Thanks

Comment: You will need the nuget packages for AppCenter. The issue is that, they made the package to work on mobile apps and not server so i am not sure if it will extract the data correctly and give you what you need.
AppCenter API may give you some ideas https://openapi.appcenter.ms/